# Unable to call public methods of class that inheriting from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to develop an app for Vuzix M300 smartglasses. This is an android device and I am using Android Studio version 3.0.1 for this.

I need to implement voice recognition for this app. So I have followed the Vuzix documentation and I have created a separate file for voice recognition called **VoiceCmdReceiver.java**.

My class extends `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
     public class VoiceCmdReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
```

I have written one public method inside this class: `sayHello()`.

Now I want to call this function from MainActivity.java but Android Studio gives error for this.

**VoiceCmdReceiver.java**

```
public class VoiceCmdReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    }

    public void sayHello() {

    }

}
```

Below it's the code for calling `sayHello()` from **MainActivity.java**

```
VoiceCmdReceiver ob = new VoiceCmdReceiver(); 
ob.sayHello();
```

For this code, Android Studio 3.0.1 doesn't show any intellisense as well.
So I am unable to call the public function of class VoiceCmdReceiver.
Vuzix provides the sample of same kind but for their sample it works.

I don't know what's wrong with my code. So guys please help me for this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can call `public` methods of a class with `object` its java.  try to clean an build the project .

Comment: should work like that. Try `import VoidCmdReceiver;`